# Is there a way to make a new div with elements appears each time that you press a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div:

```
<div class="divOne">
<g:textField name="txtField"></g:textField>
 <input type="button" id="btnAddResource" value="another" onClick="Another()" class="btnAdd"/>
</div>
```

Is there a way with JS or Jquery to make appear dynamically another equal div when the button is pressed? and How can I pass for example, each textField's  value throw params to a controller?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried?

Comment: I only have tried to make a few divs and set them like visible='hidden' and when a button is pressed make them like visible, but that makes me write a finite number of divs

Comment: you will not want duplicate id's, so maybe it would be better to use classes. Have you done any jQuery at all?

Comment: I'm working with the Jquery functionthat is down here and with classes

Comment: Huh? There are no classes mentioned anywhere here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to chanche the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.yourbutton').click(function(){
      $('body').append('<div name="divOne">
<g:textField name="txtField"></g:textField>
<g:submitButton name="btnAppear" onclick="appear()"></g:submitButton>
</div>');
});
```

This is what you want?

**for after**

```
$('.yourbutton').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().after('<div name="divOne">
<g:textField name="txtField"></g:textField>
<g:submitButton name="btnAppear" onclick="appear()"></g:submitButton>
</div>');
});
```

Comment: with this function, the new Div will be added under the div that has the pressed button? or at the end of the document?

Comment: I changed my comment upon

Comment: end of document! @PabloGlez

Comment: and What if I want to add it next to the last div?
will be something like $('divOne').append?

Comment: You would use after() because append would add it 'inside' of the div.

Comment: And I only have to insert the function inside the $(document).ready(function() { }); function right?